# How to convert some Columns to Rows

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a total of 7 columns, and only 4 of them are needed to convert into rows.
I'm using MySql. Below table is a result of multiple left joins already.

Current table

| prod_date | model | assembly | AM_Output | PM_Output | AM WHrs | PM WHrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | A | FAN | 2112 | 0 | 10.75 | 0 |
| 2023-08-02 | A | FAN | 1440 | 978 | 10.75 | 10.75 |
| 2023-08-03 | A | FAN | 1134 | 0 | 10.75 | 0 |

Target table

| prod_date | model | assembly | Shift_Out | Output | WHrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | A | FAN | AM | 2112 | 10.75 |
| 2023-08-02 | A | FAN | AM | 1440 | 10.75 |
| 2023-08-03 | A | FAN | AM | 1134 | 10.75 |
| 2023-08-01 | A | FAN | PM | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-08-02 | A | FAN | PM | 978 | 10.75 |
| 2023-08-03 | A | FAN | PM | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [IBM Documenation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/qmf/12.2.0?topic=ddfmtuss-merging-data-from-multiple-tables-into-single-column) and the [Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) this should do the trick :

```sql
SELECT prod_date, model, assembly, 'AM' as Shift_Out, AM_Output as Output, AM_WHrs as WHrs 
FROM table
UNION
SELECT t1.prod_date, t1.model, t1.assembly, 'PM' as Shift_Out, PM_Output as Output, PM_WHrs as WHrs 
FROM table AS t1
```

The `Union` should combine the first select and the second one and give you the excpected result. The `as` is used to rename the column to look like the excpected result. If the `prod_date`, `model` or `assembly` title are not correct, consider using `as` on both select.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daxelarne! Your advice worked well with the actual table!